# PHP grab grooveshark info from song URL

Tags: php, url, grooveshark

i need to grab Song infos form a grooveshark URL with PHP:

```
http://grooveshark.com/s/Soul+Meets+Body/4s4DZd?src=5
```

There is a way with out API or i need Grooveshark API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that URL redirects to `http://grooveshark.com/#!/s/Soul+Meets+Body/4s4DZd?src=5` after you visit it, but the source code before that does have some information encoded in [HTML5 Microdata](http://dev.w3.org/html5/md/) (I'm sure you'll find some [easier to read resources](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/09/microdata-html5s-best-kept-secret/) with some digging).

From the source:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/MusicRecording">
    <img src="http://images.grooveshark.com/static/amazonart/s1085803.png" alt="Plans by Death Cab for Cutie" title="Plans by Death Cab for Cutie" itemprop="image" />

    <div>
        <span itemprop="name">Soul Meets Body</span>
        by
        <span itemprop="byArtist" itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/MusicGroup">
            <a href="http://grooveshark.com/artist/Death+Cab+For+Cutie/401368"><span itemprop="name">Death Cab for Cutie</span></a>
            <meta content="http://grooveshark.com/artist/Death+Cab+For+Cutie/401368" itemprop="url" />
        </span>
        on
        <span itemprop="inAlbum" itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/MusicAlbum">
            <a href="http://grooveshark.com/album/Plans/1085803"><span itemprop="name">Plans</span></a>
            <meta content="http://grooveshark.com/album/Plans/1085803" itemprop="url" />
        </span>
    </div>

</div>
```

You'd be able to use something like PHP's [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or some other HTML parser to get that info, but I'd imagine it would be easier with their API.